# existence of a differentiable function under certain given condition

Tags: calculus

Does there exist any $f:\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that exist $x\neq 0$ with $f(x)=0$ and at any neighborhood of $x$ exist infinitely many point where $f$ does vanish also $f(0)=0,f'(0) \neq 0$

Comment: Yes. Hint: look for a function that oscillates wildly around a point $x_0$, then multiply it by $(x-x_0)^2$ to make it differentiable there.

Comment: The requirements on $f(0)$ and $f'(0)$ don't mean anything. Maybe it was $x=0$?

Comment: I edited now....

Answer (score 0):

Let g(x) = x^2 \sin(1/x),   g(0) = 0   and  set   f(x) = g(x-1)

The function f(x) satisfy the question, with x = 1.